# VBA Excel Search for cell that contain one of different word

Tags: arrays, string, excel, vba, search

I need to make a script to color or delete the row that contain at least one of the word that i need to search. For example, I've an array or simply a list of word like "alpha" "beta" "gamma" and i need to search in colum A and B where there are different words and string if these words exist, at least one of them, and then color or delete the row, but that's not the problem. This is what I've made, finding somewhere over internet, but it doesn't work. I've about 30 words to search and even more. Can you help me?

```
   Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'


For i = 2 To 1000
If Evaluate("COUNT(SEARCH({""alpha"",""beta"",""gamma""}," & Cells(i, 1).Address & "))") > 0 Then
Rows(i).Interior.Color = RGB(127, 187, 199)
GoTo Prossimo
End If
If Evaluate("COUNT(SEARCH({""alpha"",""beta"",""gamma""}," & Cells(i, 2).Address & "))") > 0 Then
Rows(i).Interior.Color = RGB(127, 187, 199)
GoTo Prossimo
End If
Prossimo:
Next i
End Sub
```

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

I would first create an array of your special words

```
words = Array("alpha", "beta", ...)
```

Then you can loop through the rows in your spreadsheet and the items in your array, looking for matches.

```
words = Array("alpha", "beta", ...)
for i = 2 to 1000
    for j = lbound(words) to ubound(words)
        if cells(i,1)=words(j) or cells(i,2)=words(j) then
            rows(i).interior.color=rgb(127,187,199)
        end if
    next j
next i
```

Comment: there's something strange but it start and finish without color nothing..

Comment: It worked fine when I tested it. What is does your input look like?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro2()
   Dim cell as Range
   Dim myWords as String

   myWords = "|alpha|beta|gamma|"
   With Worksheets("MySheet") '<--| change "MySheet" to your actual sheet name
      For Each cell in .Range("A2:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count,"A").End(xlUp).Row)
         If InStr(myWords, "|" & cell.Value & "|") > 0 or InStr(myWords, "|" & cell.Offset(,1).Value & "|") > 0 Then cell.EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(127, 187, 199)
      Next cell   
   End With
End Sub
```

Comment: seems nothing happen

Comment: I'm not by any PC to check it

Comment: I'm not by any PC to check it. So try stepping through the code and querying in the Immediate Window the values of "cell", "cell.Address", "InStr(myWords, "|" & cell.Value & "|")" and "InStr(myWords, "|" & cell.Offset (,1).Value & "|")" at every loop. The code assumes the following: 1) the relevant sheet is named after "MySheet" 2) values in columns A and B are checked from row 2 to the last non empty row of column A. 3) At every row if cell in either column A or B has the content "alpha" or "beta" or "gamma" then the whole row is colored

Comment: @BigBlack now I tested it and it works, with assumptions as per my previous comment. what is your issue?

Comment: I'm trying to see in the local variable windows but I don't know where to search to see if it find words.